# Scala REPL import SBT file

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

I have an SBT file that has the following contents:

```
name := "Scala Playground"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.netflix.rxjava" %% "rxjava-scala" % "0.19.1",
  "com.typesafe.play"  %% "play-json"    % "2.2.1"
)
```

Saved as scala-playground.sbt. I want to use this in my Scala REPL. When I tried to do the following:

```
sbt scala-playground.sbt
```

I got the following error:

```
[info] Set current project to Scala Playground (in build file:/home/joe/Desktop/)
[error] Not a valid command: scala-playground
[error] Not a valid project ID: scala-playground
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: scala-playground (similar: scala-version, scalac-options, scala-binary-version)
[error] scala-playground
[error]                 ^
```

I can't see anything stupid in my sbt file. Could anyone throw some light on it? Is this a proper way to get dependencies inside my Scala REPL?

All I want to do is to get in some dependencies inside my Scala REPL, so that I can quickly run and evaluate certain libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command line arguments are `sbt` commands, not the file you want to use. Just go to the directory with `scala-playground.sbt` file and run from there:

```
sbt console
```

`sbt` should automatically load the `scala-playground.sbt` file from current directory and open Scala console.